# jquery: how are HTML elements ordered when I select them using jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there some documentation regarding the order of returned HTML elements by a jquery selector. So for example if I do

```
$('div.experience_entries_list input.experience_order_array').each(function() 
{
    alert(this.value);
});
```

, can I assume that the returned elements will come in the order that they are positioned in the html? I've checked this and it seems to be so but I want to be 100% sure before releasing the code built with this assumption :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, as of jQuery 1.3.2 elements are returned in document order.

From the [release notes](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.3.2):

> **Elements Returned in Document Order**
>
> This is a change to jQuery's selector
> engine that re-orders the returned
> results to be in document order,
> instead of the order in which the
> selectors were passed in. This change
> was done in order to be in compliance
> with the [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-api/) specification
> (which jQuery uses, internally, in
> browsers that support it).